# React js components rerender when submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a Mobx storage and a modal window component, where I use a form to push all the props into a cart array in storage as an object. Here's the code for the storage:

```
interface p{
    p:object,
}
class CartStore{
    cartItems:Object[]=[];
    cartPrice:number=0;
    constructor(){
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }
     handleSubmit=(p:any)=>{
         this.cartItems.push(p)
    }
    

}
const cartStore=new CartStore();
export default cartStore;
```

Then here's the modal window:

```
import React from 'react'
import pizzaStore from './stores/PizzaStore'
import {observer} from "mobx-react-lite"
import cartStore from './stores/CartStore';

function ModalWindowComponent({activeModal, setActiveModal}:any){
    let modalPrice:number;
    let modalSize:number;
    let modalName:string;
    let modalDesc:string;
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption]=React.useState("small")
    const handleSetOption=(e:any)=>{
            setSelectedOption(e.target.value)
        }
    return (
        <div className={activeModal?"modal active":"modal"}  onClick={()=>{setActiveModal(false); setSelectedOption("small")}}>
            <div className="modal-content" onClick={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation()}}>
                <div className="modal-content-header">
                    <button onClick={()=>setActiveModal(false)}>Close</button>
                </div>
                <img src={pizzaStore.modalProps.imageUrl} className="modal-content-img"/>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-name">{modalName=pizzaStore.modalProps.name}</p>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-desc">{modalDesc=pizzaStore.modalProps.description}</p>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-size">{modalSize=pizzaStore.setSize(selectedOption)}см</p>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-weight">{pizzaStore.setWeight(selectedOption)}грамм</p>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-price">{modalPrice=pizzaStore.setPrice(selectedOption, pizzaStore.modalProps.price)}Руб.</p>
                <form className="modal-content-sizes-form">
                    <label>
                    
                    <input  name="radio-size"value="small" type="radio" onChange={handleSetOption} checked={!activeModal||selectedOption==="small"} className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"/>Маленькая</label>
                    <label>
                    <input  name="radio-size"value="medium" type="radio"  onChange={handleSetOption}checked={selectedOption==="medium"}className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"/>Средняя</label>
                    <label>
                    <input name="radio-size"value="big" type="radio"  onChange={handleSetOption}checked={selectedOption==="big"} className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"/>Большая</label>
                    <button onClick={()=>{cartStore.handleSubmit({modalName, modalDesc, modalSize, modalPrice  }); setActiveModal(false);console.log(cartStore.cartItems)}}>Добавить</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default observer(ModalWindowComponent)
```

Why does the whole application rerender when you push the button?

Comment: Sounds like you may just need to `preventDefault` on the submit event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add onSubmit Handler to the form.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>
```

and in handleSubmit, you have to write something like:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
   event.preventDefault();
   // other body
}
```

It is the default behaviour of an HTML form to go to the page defined in the action attribute of the form on submit. Since we are not providing action attribute to the form component, it reloads the page. event.preventDefault() prevents this default behaviour to happen.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of `form`. If you are manually handling the submit you should stop the default behavior.

```
<form onsubmit="post();return false;">
//content
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this  :

```
<button onClick={(event)=>{
    //call your functions
    event.preventDefault();
}
```